# Why does my phone say "Verizon Wireless" when I receive a phone call?

Tags: text-to-speech, cellular-radio

Whenever I receive a phone call on my DROID RAZR MAXX, the phone speaks the words "Verizon Wireless" in a female voice and then begins playing the ringtone.

If I put the phone into airplane mode, the same female voice says the words "Loss of service". Then when I turn airplane mode off, she says "Verizon Wireless" again, sometimes twice in a row.

What's going on? What is this feature? How do I enable or disable this?

My phone is running stock JB 4.1.2.

Comment: Could be TalkBack, or some other accessibility settings, perhaps. Check in `Settings -> Accessibility` and see if anything is enabled? That might be a good first step at least.

Comment: TalkBack is off. I went through every setting I could think of _before_ I asked this question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These voices were the result of having the so-called "Roaming tone" enabled in the **Sound** settings.

Strangely, the description of this setting is:

> Roaming tone
>   Set notification tone informing the status of cellular service

After disabling this option, she no longer speaks to me when I receive a phone call or turn on/off airplane mode.

Though I have no idea how a speaking voice is considered a "notification tone"...

[image: Sound settings]